# React Redux Firebase - isLoaded only false for the first document when using firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux-firebase, redux-firestore

In my app I use `react-redux-firebase` version `2.5.1` with `redux-firestore` version `^0.13.0`. I render a list of conversations with customers (called threads) and each time a user goes to another thread, until it's loaded I want him to see a loading spinner. The issue of mine is that only when I go to a thread for the first time after app deployment the spinner shows, after that each time I change a thread the method `isLoaded` is always true, even though I see that for some seconds the page shows the previous thread. Has anyone met with something like that and can help me how to solve it ?

Here is my component

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    const customerId = props.match.params.id;
    return {
        thread: state.firestore.data.thread,
        ...
    };
};

export default compose(
    withStyles(styles),
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
    firestoreConnect(props => [
        {
            collection: "thread",
            doc: props.customerId,
            storeAs: "thread"
        }
...
    ])
)(ThreadView);
```

Here is my render method

```
       render() {
            const {firebase, thread} = this.props;            
            const res = !isLoaded(thread); // after the first load it's always false
            console.log(`customerId: ${customerId}, isLoaded: ${res}`)
            if (res) {
                return <LoadingSpinner/>;
            }
...
```

Comment: I think this is the expected functionality. In general, the `isLoaded` property indicates the first load of content. For your purpose, I think the `isLoading` needed.

Comment: ok nice but I don't see in the `react-redux-firebase` api method called `isLoading` so what do you mean exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this issue and so far haven't found a satisfactory solution. However, I did find a workaround:

Write a custom `isLoaded` function that checks for any requests in progress:

```
const checkIsLoaded = function(firestore) {
    return !Object.values(firestore.status.requesting).find(isRequesting => isRequesting);
};
```

Because all the current pending request's statuses (true/false) are saved in the redux store under `firestore.status.requesting` we can check this, and see if any requests are currently still loading!

It's not an ideal solution because it will check ALL in-progress requests, not just the specific one you want to check. However, depending on your use case, this may be enough.